# Why didn't Chibi-usa initially recognize Sailors Mercury, Mars, Jupiter, & Venus as her friends?

Tags: sailor-moon

In the R season of the classic anime of *Sailor Moon*, Chibi-usa had a flashback memory of her surprise birthday party in the 30th century Crystal Tokyo, in which Sailor Mercury, Sailor Mars, Sailor Jupiter, and Sailor Venus were present (Wiseman made use of the piece of memory of the span of time during which the secret about the surprise was being kept from her in order to turn Chibi-usa into Black Lady). Chibi-usa also had a faint memory of the same four sailor soldiers fleeing with her while Crystal Tokyo was being attacked, but in this memory, the four people are darkened silhouettes. I can understand that, due to the trauma of the attack and worry about her mom, Chibi-usa might not remember clearly who helped her escape. After these events, she time-traveled to the 20th century where she met Sailors Moon, Mercury, Mars, Jupiter, and Venus in their solider forms (as well as met them in their civilian forms).

*If Chibi-usa had the clear memory of the birthday party, why didn't she immediately recognize those same four sailor soldiers when she "re-met" them in the 20th century?* Didn't the party scene indicate that they were her friends and she knew their names?

Is this a plot hole?

(The manga does not feature the birthday party memory, so I am looking for answers regarding an in-universe explanation for the classic anime canon.)

Comment: i'm pretty sure Pluto was telling Chibi-usa not to trust anyone for any reason even if they looked similar, but i remember this from the original dub so the episodes may have been tampered with

Comment: @Memor-X, This sounds promising. Could you provide an episode number that I can check to see if the Japanese version contains the same dialogue?

Comment: she didnt even trust her parents despite knowing all of a sudden who they are

Comment: @Thomas Can you give an episode number for Chibi-usa knowing Mamoru and Usagi were her parents and yet didn't trust them? If I recall correctly, in the manga she knew from the beginning that Sailor Moon was her mother, whereas in the classic anime King Endymion had only told her that Sailor Moon helped people in the past without mentioning that Sailor Moon was the past form of her mother Neo Queen Serenity, and Pluto didn't mention it to her either. I believe that Chibi-usa did not find out the past identities of her parents until some time after Sailor Moon and Tuxedo Kamen found out.

Answer (score 3):

I asked [a fan](http://kimiski.deviantart.com) who is not part of this SE community this question and she responded:

> . . . you found loop holes in the anime. The whole thing in *R* where Chibi-Usa didn't know Sailor Moon was her mom, or the four senshi were her friends, the same as in the future was in my opinion, a horrible decision on the anime creators side. In the manga she knew before she even went back into the past that Sailor Moon/Usagi Tsukino and her mother was one in the same. In the anime all she knows is stories of a senshi called Sailor Moon in the past that her dad told her. The fact that the inner senshi of the past and future look exactly the same, have the same names, etc, is completely side stepped by the anime's production. Like really? Are we supposed to believe she's so stupid she couldn't put those two things together? But alas, they try anyway.

Her interpretation is that in the 90s anime, Chibi-usa did know the names and appearances of Sailors Mercury, Mars, Jupiter, and Venus in the 30th century before she time-traveled to the 20th century, and that failing to recognize them in the past is a plot hole.

Answer (score 0):

This is my hypothesis and you can pick it apart all you want. My theory is that:

1. Chibiusa did know who Sailor Moon was and who the Sailor scouts were, but perhaps because Chibiusa traveled in time, perhaps the shock of time travel partially wiped her memory (since she did recognize Usagi/Serena as the holder of the silver crystal). Or,

2. Chibiusa knows the identity of Sailor Moon and Sailor Senshi and is pretending not to for one reason or another.

On the question of whether Chibiusa knows that Usagi is Sailor Moon, check episode 65 about a dispute over love between Minako and Makoto. In that episode, after the fight is over, Chibiusa pops up in the background like she'd been there the whole time, so if she didn't know before episode 65, she knows now. (or at least is putting 2 and 2 together)